# How to populate textboxes with json data by selecting dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

`    public partial class DropDownApi : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         string _URL = "/api/Insurance";

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(_URL);
            req.Method = "GET";
            // req.Headers.Add("key");
            req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader re = new StreamReader(stream);
            String json = re.ReadToEnd();
            json = "{\"InsuranceDetails\":" + json + "}";
            wrapper w = (wrapper)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(json, typeof(wrapper));


            ddlinsurance.DataSource = w.InsuranceDetails;
            ddlinsurance.DataBind();
        }
        public class wrapper
        {
            public List<insurance_master> InsuranceDetails { get; set; }
        }`<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlinsurance" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" DataTextField="policy_number"></asp:DropDownList>`
```

`I am having a dropdownlist filled with json data(policy_number) and now when i select the policy_number from dropdown it has to display remaining details in the textboxes by matching the selected policy_number.I have used MVC WebApi service for my project.
Can anyone please help me!!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: show us what you have done

Comment: please include the code you've written so far and tell us where you're stuck. In any case, you'll need to research how to approach this. An internet search for the title of this post will undoubtedly get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but I think this will help you..

### Html

```
<select id="list">
     <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```

### JavaScript

```
// sample json data
var sampleJson = [
    { 'policy_number': 1, 'data': 'policy 1', 'display': 'one' },
    { 'policy_number': 2, 'data': 'policy 2', 'display': 'two' },
    { 'policy_number': 3, 'data': 'policy 3', 'display': 'three' }
];

//get select element using id
var select = document.getElementById('list');

//append option to select list with values from sampleJson
for (var i = 0; i < sampleJson.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = sampleJson[i]['policy_number'];
    option.text = sampleJson[i]['display'];
    select.appendChild(option);
}          
var input = document.getElementById('inp');

//onchange event handler for select 
select.onchange = function()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sampleJson.length; i++) {
        //selecetd value present in sampleJson set it into textbox
        if(sampleJson[i]['policy_number'] == this.value)
        {
            input.value = sampleJson[i]['data'];
        }
        // check the value is not empty(for default Choose option)
        if(this.value == '')
        {
            input.value = this.value;
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JTL3M/8/)</kbd>**